# Axcrypt launch encrypted file without prompt

Tags: encryption

Can AxCrypt be made to launch an encrypted program with the prompt asking the following question?

> The encrypted file is a program.  Do you want to allow MyProgram.bat
>   to run?

My version is 1.7.2867.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under HKLM or HKCU Software\Axantum\AxCrypt you can set the DWORD value named `AllowPrograms` to non-zero to disable the prompt.